# Stage independent stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure which is copying data from one schema to another. Therefore, I could grant the user rights, so it can access the second schema in the stored procedure or I could use database links.

Now, my problem is that both solutions require the script to be stage dependent. My database link name or schema name is not the same on every test stage.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Just an example of using grants to access the schema directly:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE TRANSFER_HISTORY
IS
    value NUMBER := 0;
    value2 NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO value FROM schema1.table1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO value2 FROM schema2.table2;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( SQLERRM );
END;
```

**Solution**

As [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave) mentioned, synonyms seems to be the way to go.
As mentioned [here,](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4385839/creating-synonym-for-schema-user) Oracle doesn't have the functionality activated for schemata per default.
You can either enable the Feature or create synonyms for the Tables you need it for. I will do the second approach since I only need access to 1 other table.

Comment: What does "test stage" mean here?  Potentially, you want to use synonyms to provide an abstraction layer so that you don't have to hard-code schema names in your code.  But I don't understand how "test stage" relates to your database's structure so I'm not sure.

Comment: Test Stage in means of a Staging Environment. We have a Database to test everything and one for production.

Comment: If you have a single environment that is trying to be dev, test, and staging, it would generally make more sense to have each environment be a separate PDB.  Or have separate databases running on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the same database, then don't use database link as you can do that by granting privileges to another user.

If certain things differ from one situation to another, make it dynamic by passing parameters to the procedure. In that case, you'll have to use dynamic SQL (i.e. run statements using `execute immediate`). As you'll be using tables' names in the procedure, you can't use bind variables, but will have to concatenate table name to the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes. I thinking granting is better in my scenario too. Is it possible to pass schema name to the stored Procedure? I'm not talking about some Variable Value like a Number or something which changes per Stage, but about the Schema Name which differs.